# How to add some url rewrite to WHMCS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, whmcs

I'm trying to setup a classic .htaccess file for url rewriting.

For the moment I'm trying to simply rewrite `login.php` to `login`

I have tried using the following .htacess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Not Directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Not file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Not Link ?? No Need.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^login/$        login.php               [L]
```

Which gives me the following when I try to access `http://MYIP/login`

```
http://MYIP/https://MYIP/login/
```

And I also tried using the following :

```
### BEGIN - WHMCS managed rules - DO NOT EDIT BETWEEN WHMCS MARKERS ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteBase is set to "/" so rules do not need updating if the
# installation directory is relocated.  It is imperative that
# there is also a RewriteCond rule later that can effectively get
# the actual value by comparison against the request URI.
#
# If there are _any_ other RewriteBase directives in this file,
# the last entry will take precedence!
RewriteBase /


# Redirect directories to an address with slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

# Send all remaining (routable paths) through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Determine and use the actual base
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
### END - WHMCS managed rules - DO NOT EDIT BETWEEN WHMCS MARKERS ###



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule     ^/login/$           ^/login.php$    [L]
```

And I got the same result.

Under the administration panel in WHMCS I set the url rewrite to Basic URLs.

Opening in private navigation I have error 404.

Comment: Are you getting any error when you hit URL `http://localhost:80/login`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Nop no error, when I open it in private navigation I have error 404 now

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Looks like you already had 1 Rule for non existing directories and non existing files so place your Login rule before it. I have put htaccess rule file here only from `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` to `</IfModule>` here.

```
### BEGIN - WHMCS managed rules - DO NOT EDIT BETWEEN WHMCS MARKERS ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase is set to "/" so rules do not need updating if the
# installation directory is relocated.  It is imperative that
# there is also a RewriteCond rule later that can effectively get
# the actual value by comparison against the request URI.
#
# If there are _any_ other RewriteBase directives in this file,
# the last entry will take precedence!
RewriteBase /

# Redirect directories to an address with slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^login/?$  login.php$ [NC,L]

# Send all remaining (routable paths) through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Determine and use the actual base
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
### END - WHMCS managed rules - DO NOT EDIT BETWEEN WHMCS MARKERS ###
```

Answer (score 2):

After some search and help from @RavinderSingh13, I get to the following working `.htaccess` :

```
### BEGIN - WHMCS managed rules - DO NOT EDIT BETWEEN WHMCS MARKERS ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase is set to "/" so rules do not need updating if the
# installation directory is relocated.  It is imperative that
# there is also a RewriteCond rule later that can effectively get
# the actual value by comparison against the request URI.
#
# If there are _any_ other RewriteBase directives in this file,
# the last entry will take precedence!
RewriteBase /

# Redirect directories to an address with slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Change
RewriteRule ^login$ ./login.php [L,NC]


# Send all remaining (routable paths) through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Determine and use the actual base
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
### END - WHMCS managed rules - DO NOT EDIT BETWEEN WHMCS MARKERS ###
```